# Exporting displayed layer by pulling its name from ui.Select widget using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm making an app in which a user can select one of multiple layers displayed in a map and export it.

I have a *ui.Select* widget that shows the names of the displayed images, so the user can pick the one that it needs. Then a *ui.Button* for executing the export function.

I have tried to come up with a function so the ui.Button reads the value stored in the *ui.Select* and matches it with the names of the layers displayed in the map, but I haven't been successful.

I know there is a *getEeObject()* function but I haven't been able to make it work using only the name of an image (the name of the images is important for me because it makes it understandable for the user to know which image is viewing and exporting).

Here is an example code that ilustrates what I want to achieve:

```
///////APP CREATION/////////
//Create and display the main panels
var mappingPanel = ui.Map({
    center: {'lat': -41.318, 'lon': -72.985, 'zoom': 11}
  });
var widgetPanel = ui.Panel({
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow(), 
    style: {stretch: 'horizontal', height: '100%', width: '400px'}
});
ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(ui.SplitPanel(mappingPanel, widgetPanel));
//Create ui.Select where to show the names of the displayed images
var selector = ui.Select({items: [], placeholder: 'Displayed layers'});
//Create ui.Button to start export of selected image
var button = ui.Button({label: 'Export selected layer'});
//Add widgets to the widgetPanel
widgetPanel.add(selector).add(button);
//////////////////////////////


//Define collection
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");

//Filter collection
var l8Filtered = l8
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-12-01')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 30));
print('filtered collection', l8Filtered);

//Display the median, min and max of the filtered collection (for example purposes)
var median = l8Filtered.median();
var min = l8Filtered.min();
var max = l8Filtered.max();

var medianImage = ui.Map.Layer(median, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000, gamma:1.3}, 'median');
var minImage = ui.Map.Layer(min, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000, gamma:1.3}, 'min');
var maxImage = ui.Map.Layer(max, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000, gamma:1.3}, 'max');

mappingPanel.add(medianImage).add(minImage).add(maxImage);
  
//Get the name of the displayed layers and show them in the ui.Select widget
var layers = mappingPanel.layers();
print('displayed layers', layers);
var names = [];
  layers.forEach(function(x){
    var lay_name = x.getName();
    names.push(lay_name);
  });
var updateSelector = selector.items().reset(names);
  
//Export an ee.Object displayed in the map by accessing to its name through the ui.Select widget
button.onClick(function(){
  var imageName = selector.getValue();
  print('image name', imageName);
  // var eeObject = (?)
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: eeObject,
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:32718',
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
});
```

And here is the link to the same code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d10cb0971c82dccbe3a685cf3cdb1760

**Is there a way to get an *ee.Object* directly from the map by pulling its name from a ui.Select widget?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dictionary mapping name to object when you make the list of names.  Then use it to look up the object when the selection is made.

```
var lDict = {};
var names = []
layers.forEach(function(x){
  var lay_name = x.getName();
  lDict[lay_name] = x.getEeObject();
  names.push(lay_name)
});
var updateSelector = selector.items().reset(names)
  
//Export an ee.Object displayed in the map by accessing to its name through the ui.Select widget
button.onClick(function(){
  var imageName = selector.getValue();
  print('image name', imageName);
  print(lDict[imageName])
});
```